# How to enter only number and decimal 4 digit

Tags: javascript, c#, decimal, keycode, digits

I use JavaScript. I want to enter only number and decimal 4 digit.
But i try decimal only 4 digit not working.

**ASP**

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtRangeFrom" Runat="server" onkeypress="validNumberAndDecimal(this);" Style="text-align: center; width:100px;" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "range_start") %>'>                                                                      </asp:TextBox>
```

**Javascript**

```
 function validNumberAndDecimal(sender)
        {
           var operator = document.getElementById('ddlOperator').value;        

           if(operator == 'AWN') 
           {
                //condition Nomber Only
           }
           else // TOT Condition decimal 4 digit
           {               
                var caretPos = 0;
                if (document.selection)
                {
                    sender.focus();
                    var Sel = document.selection.createRange();
                    Sel.moveStart('character', -sender.value.length);
                    caretPos = Sel.text.length;
                }
                else if (sender.selectionStart || sender.selectionStart == '0')
                {
                    caretPos = sender.selectionStart;
                }

                var keyCode = window.event.keyCode;
                var str = document.getElementById(sender.id).value;

                if ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || (keyCode == 8))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (keyCode == 46) {
                    var curVal = document.activeElement.value;
                    if (curVal != null && curVal.trim().indexOf('.') == -1) --> not working
                    {                       
                        return true;                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        window.event.returnValue = false;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    window.event.returnValue = false;
                    return false;
                }   
           }           
        }
```

**Result now:**
40.0123456789

**but i want decimal 4 git:**
40.0123 or 4.1245 or 789456.1234

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toFixed(4);`

So, something like this:

```
var curVal = document.activeElement.value;
curVal = curVal.toFixed(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Which will give you the required `answer`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ergtB/229/)

hope it helps

**Html:**

```
<input type="text"  data-m-dec="4" class="number">
```

**Jquery:**

```
  $(".number").autoNumeric();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the awesome AutoNumeric library which has zero dependency (https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/).

In order to get a number with 4 decimals, you can just do :

```
const aNElement = new AutoNumeric('.number', { decimalPlaces : 4 });
```

That's it :)